# Can't understand why using CAST errors out but using CONVERT does not?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The following code that executes without any issue:

```
Select 
#ICDCodes.ICD_Code,
#ICDCodes.Description,
Count(#DiseaseIndex.VstIntID) AS 'Total Count',
Sum(DATEDIFF(dd,#DiseaseIndex.AdmitDtSrt,#DiseaseIndex.DschrgDtTm )) as 'Total LOS',
ISNULL(AVG(CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,2),DATEDIFF(DAY,#DiseaseIndex.AdmitDtSrt,#DiseaseIndex.DschrgDtTm))),0) as 'Total Avg LOS'
FROM #DiseaseIndex LEFT JOIN #ICDCodes on #DiseaseIndex.VstIntID = #ICDCodes.VstIntID
WHERE ICD_Type IN ('P','S')
GROUP BY #ICDCodes.ICD_Code, #ICDCodes.Descriptio
```

but this code throws an error:

```
SELECT
#ICDCodes.ICD_Code, 
#ICDCodes.Description, 
Count(#DiseaseIndex.VstIntID) AS 'Total Count', 
Sum(CAST(DATEDIFF(dd,#DiseaseIndex.AdmitDtSrt,#DiseaseIndex.DschrgDtTm )AS NUMERIC(8,2))) AS 'Total LOS', 
ISNULL(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,#DiseaseIndex.AdmitDtSrt,#DiseaseIndex.DschrgDtTm) AS NUMERIC(8,2)),0) as 'Total Avg LOS'
FROM #DiseaseIndex LEFT JOIN #ICDCodes on #DiseaseIndex.VstIntID = #ICDCodes.VstIntID
WHERE ICD_Type IN ('P','S') 
GROUP BY #ICDCodes.ICD_Code, #ICDCodes.Description`
```

This is the Error it generates:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 191
>   Column '#DiseaseIndex.AdmitDtSrt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 191
>   Column '#DiseaseIndex.DschrgDtTm' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Basically it is the same code with the exception that one set uses `CAST()` and the other one uses `CONVERT()`.

Can someone explain why the `CAST` requires adding the dates to the `GROUP BY` statement while the `CONVERT` does not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please send the complete query?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please, next time when someone asks you to edit a post, let them know you did with a comment addressed to them.

Answer (score 3):

### Update

In the second query you've forgot the `AVG`:

first query:
    `ISNULL(`**`AVG(`**`CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,2),DATEDIFF(DAY,#DiseaseIndex.AdmitDtSrt,#DiseaseIndex.DschrgDtTm))`**)**`,0) as 'Total Avg LOS`

second query:

`ISNULL(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,#DiseaseIndex.AdmitDtSrt,#DiseaseIndex.DschrgDtTm) AS NUMERIC(8,2)),0) as 'Total Avg LOS'`

### First version:

(This was correct for the first version of the question.)

This is because you use `NUMERIC(8,2)` in the `convert`, but `DECIMAL(8,2)` in the `cast`.

Though numeric and decimal are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql) to be interchangeable synonyms, having a numeric in he group by clause and a decimal in the select clause will raise that error.

Here is a simple demo:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    col1 int,
    col2 int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),
(4,2),(5,2),(6,2),
(7,3)

SELECT  CAST(Col2 as NUMERIC(8,2)), 
        AVG(Col1)
FROM @T
GROUP BY CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), Col2)
```

Results:

> Column '@T.col2' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

However, if you change the select to `decimal` or the group by to `numeric`, the error message is gone and the select returns the result set:

```
SELECT  CAST(Col2 as DECIMAL(8,2)), 
        AVG(Col1)
FROM @T
GROUP BY CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), Col2)
```

Results:

```
1.00    2
2.00    5
3.00    7
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/WCFH29813)

Comment: I follow that logic and it makes sense to be consistent with type conversion., but I'm not using both in the same report. I have to separate version of the coded: one version uses the CAST and the other version uses CONVERT.

Comment: Well, unless you share the query (or even better, a simplified version of it) and sample data, there is not much more I can help with...